# I have message contract which contains complex types

Tags: c#, wcf

I have message contract which contains complex types. After filling data in DataContract class i am passing the object of datacontract to message contract constructor. Data contract has multiple complex types. I want to rename response xml elements.Since, it is a complex type i am able to rename the contract class name. When i try to rename it properties it is created a tag outside the class name tag.

```
[MessageContract]
public class GetDetailsFromCardNumberResponse
{
    [MessageBodyMember]
    public GetDetailsFromCardNumberResponseBody Body { get; set; }

    [MessageBodyMember(Name = "PatronAccountCardValidation")]
    public PatronAccountCardValidation PatronValidation { get; set; }

    public GetDetailsFromCardNumberResponse() { }

    public GetDetailsFromCardNumberResponse(GetDetailsFromCardNumberResponseBody body)
    {
       PatronValidation = body.GetDetailsFromCardNumberResult;
    }
}
```

In the above PatronAccountCardValidation is the complex type.Inside the constructor i tried to assign to its properties. But it falls outside the base element as below

```
<PatronAccountCardValidation >
</PatronAccountCardValidation >
<PatronId></Patron>
```

I have found why it happening. But not sure how to resolve. Kindly suggest

Comment: have you tried to add [KnownType(typeof(PatronAccountCardValidation))] attribute in your GetDetailsFromCardNumberResponse?

Comment: Yes, and do the same with those classes with dependency/reference with other class.

Comment: Hi actually i have a complex type... that type should come as a header..properties should come as member..

Answer (score 0):

Try to add XmlAttributes to control the xml serialization:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "YourCustomClassName")]
public class GetDetailsFromCardNumberResponse
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "YourCustomAttibuteName")]
    public PatronAccountCardValidation PatronValidation { get; set; }
}
```

Hope it helps